# How to get the preceding characters of a given string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a scraper in Node JS and I want it to look for all `.css` files.

I'm passing the HTML of the page as a string and simply using `indexOf()` to look for instances of `.css`, eg:

```
const searchHTMLIndex = htmlString.indexOf(".css");
if (searchHTMLIndex > 0) {
          let tempString = htmlString.substring(0, searchHTMLIndex);
          let lineNumber = tempString.split('\n').length;
          jsonObj[getPageId] = pageObj;
          pageObj.pageUrl = url;
          return pageObj.searchTerm[item] = "CSS on line number: " + lineNumber;
}
```

However, I'd like to get the full CSS file name (and full path) if possible, eg: `/assets/css/myCSSfile.css`.

How do I get the preceding characters of a given string (up until, say `"` or `=`)?

Comment: You have the index.  Just back up one by one until you find what you're looking for.  It's quite dangerous to assume that every mention of the string ".css" is a CSS file name.  Why don't you do it the right way and use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML?

Comment: @TimRoberts BS is Python, this is JavaScript. There are some NPM libraries for parsing HTML.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts. Don't know Python and havent heard of BeautifulSoup, but might be worth checking it out

Comment: You can use a regular expression: `/[^'"]*\.css/`

Comment: @Barmar Maybe `[^'"=]*` is safer. Since `<style href=foo/bar.css />` without quotes is also valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could a regexp to extract `href` from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL">`:

```js
const htmlString = `
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=312b43e78b51">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=134475a13287">
    <link type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Channels/channels.css?v=a4d77abedec3" rel="stylesheet">
`;
  
const cssUrls = htmlString.match(/(?<=<link[^>]*(rel="stylesheet")?[^>]+href=")[^"]+(?=([^>]*rel="stylesheet")?)/g);
console.log(cssUrls);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsdom` to parse the HTML:

https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

```
import {JSDOM} from 'jsdom';

const dom = new JSDOM(htmlString);
const cssUrls = [...dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]')].map(link => link.href);
```